# Binding values while or for loop

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

In my intuition, if I bind a value in the loop, I believed UI updates automatically. 
This is my test code:

**binding**

```
private string _client1 {get; set;}
public string client1
{
    get => _client1;
    set
    {
        _client1 = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(client1));
    }
}
```

**Function**

```
public async void UpdateUI()
{
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        DispatcherHelper.CheckBeginInvokeOnUI(async () =>
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                _client1 = i.ToString();
                RaisePropertyChanged(_client1);

                await Task.Delay(200);
            }
        });
    }).ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

**Result** 
`0` is shown and not changed in UI.

**Expected Result** 
`0 1 2 ... 10`

I want the value to be changed continuously in UI. What is the problem with this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the control is bound to the `client1` property, then that is what you should be changing, not the backing field `_client1`:

```
client1 = i.ToString();
```

And since the setter for `client1` already calls `RaisePropertyChanged`, you don't need this line inside your loop:

```
RaisePropertyChanged(_client1);
```

Comment: Holly... It works well. Sorry for bothering you.

Comment: @h1d3r00t No trouble at all